# Tab bar item image higher than the other images on tab bar

Tags: xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

In my tab bar, one of the tab bar items is higher than the others. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrSCr.png). I tried using other images, and using system images, deleting the view and re-adding it. Every time this one item is higher than the others. What can I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That icon might have `extra space`*(Padding)* at bottom. There is problem with image. To check set second tab bar item icon at first position.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following steps:

- Make sure your icon is .png file
- Please resize and rename your icon with following:

  75x75 pixels (and rename as iconName@3x.png),

  50x50 pixels (and rename as iconName@2x.png), and

  25x25 pixels (rename as iconName.png
- drag and drop your icons into 'Assets.xcassets'

It will work. thanks!

Comment: Please have a screenshot of ‘Assets.xcassets’

Comment: Ok I will upload one although that’s not the problem. I used the same image on the other tab bar items and they are not effected. They stay in postition